# How to watch instance method operator() result in VSCode C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, operator-overloading, watch, vscode-debugger

My code is as follows:

```
class Foo{
    public:
    int operator()(int i)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int operator++(int i)
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    int a = foo++;
    int b = foo(0);
    float c = 0;
}
```

The problem is that I am not able to watch `foo(0)`:

[image]

`foo++` is visible normally.

I think the reason is that overloaded function call operator becomes a FunctionObject type (see here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Is it possible to watch it?

Comment: Try watching `foo.operator()(0)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As [n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m](https://stackoverflow.com/users/775806/n-1-8e9-wheres-my-share-m) commented, `foo.operator()(0)` works for me:

[image]